# how to filter nodes in xml using xslt..?

Tags: xslt

suppose i have this xml:

```
<college>
    <student>
        <name>amit</name>
        <file>/abc/kk/final.c</file>
        <rollno>22</rollno>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>sumit</name>
        <file>/abc/kk/up.h</file>
        <rollno>23</rollno>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>nikhil</name>
        <file>/xyz/up.cpp</file>
        <rollno>24</rollno>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>bharat</name>
        <file>/abc/kk/down.h</file>
        <rollno>25</rollno>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>ajay</name>
        <file>/simple/st.h</file>
        <rollno>27</rollno>
    </student>
</college>
```

i am using for-each in ".xsl" to display all the entries of nodes, but i only want to display the entries of those node only in which file name starts with "/abc/kk" as i am new to xslt..

please provide me solution.

i am using :

```
<xsl:for-each select="college/student">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="file"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="rollno"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please provide nicely formatted XML so we can better understand your question

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that uses the fundamental features of XSLT such as templates and push style processing. A detailed explanation is provided.

Answer (score 7):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


 <xsl:template match="student[starts-with(file,'/abc/kk')]">
  <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="student/*">
     <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="student"/>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<college>
    <student>
        <name>amit</name>
        <file>/abc/kk/final.c</file>
        <rollno>22</rollno>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>sumit</name>
        <file>/abc/kk/up.h</file>
        <rollno>23</rollno>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>nikhil</name>
        <file>/xyz/up.cpp</file>
        <rollno>24</rollno>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>bharat</name>
        <file>/abc/kk/down.h</file>
        <rollno>25</rollno>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>ajay</name>
        <file>/simple/st.h</file>
        <rollno>27</rollno>
    </student>
</college>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<tr>
   <td>amit</td>
   <td>/abc/kk/final.c</td>
   <td>22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>sumit</td>
   <td>/abc/kk/up.h</td>
   <td>23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>bharat</td>
   <td>/abc/kk/down.h</td>
   <td>25</td>
</tr>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **A template matching any `student` having a `file` child whose string value starts with '/abc/kk'**.  This just puts the generated contents in a wrapper `tr` element.
2. **A template matching any `student`** that has no body and effectively deletes it (doesn't copy this element to the output). This template has a lower priority than the first one, because the first one is more specific. Therefore, only `student` elements that are not matched by the first template are processed with the second template.
3. **A template matching any child element of any `student` element**. This just wraps the content into a `td` element.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="college/student[starts-with(file, '/abc/kk')]">
<!-- ... -->
```

The brackets `[ ]` delimit a "filter", and inside that filter you can have functions like `starts-with()`

Comment: @kuldeep: please check this answer as correct. It will help you to get more people willing to answer your further question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `[..]` in `match`:

```
<xsl:template match="college/student[starts-with(file, '/abc/kk')]">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="file"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="rollno"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```